# "Reduce the amount of water" vs. "reduce the water amount"

Tags: prepositional-phrases, attributive-nouns

The first "sounds" better to me but I'm trying to figure out if there is a formal rule regarding which one is more proper in American English:

> 1. reduce the amount of water
> 2. reduce the water amount.

Comment: It depends upon context. But, generally the first is correct.

Comment: Though nouns are often used attributively (before another noun, behaving rather like an adjective), they are also often avoided for certain pairings. 'Pile of logs' and 'logpile' both work. 'Gasholder' is used but 'holder of gas' sounds unnatural. It's the other way round with 'water amount' and 'amount of water', as seen [here](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=reduce+the+amount+of+water%2Creduce+the+water+amount&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Creduce%20the%20amount%20of%20water%3B%2Cc0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, seeing as "amount" is a noun, you would be right to say "amount of water". Substitute the word 'water' with something else, and you will see that it doesn't sound right the second way:

Reduce the flour amount vs reduce the amount of flour

By saying "water amount" you are turning water into an adjective, like saying the blue amount.